# Bootstrap / vue responsive 'snake' columns, where alternate 'rows' are reversed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, layout

Bit of a thorny problem, hopefully someone may be able to shed some insight.

I'm building a system in laravel/vue/bootstrap where I'm looping through some objects and looking to display them in the following pattern.

```
1 2 3
6 5 4
7 8 9
```

, and for this to be responsive, so if the screen is resized we get

```
1 2 3 4
8 7 6 5
9
```

etc. The elements form a 'snake' pattern.

Anyone think of any tips how to achieve this?

Comment: I answered the question, but didn't take the "reversed" aspect into consideration. Apologies. I can think of a way to do this, but need to ask, are you child elements a fixed width?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I came up with something in the end that seemed to work well enough.

Answer (score 0):

Came up with something in the end. I used three breakpoints, large has 6 columns, medium 4 columns, small 3 columns.

e.g.   ( results is an array of the elements that need to display )

```
<div class="col-4 d-sm-block d-md-none mb-3" v-for="(course,index) in snakeOrderedResults(results,3)">

...

<div class="col-md-3 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none mb-3" v-for="(course,index) in snakeOrderedResults(results,4)" >


...

<div class="col-lg-2 d-none d-lg-block mb-3" v-for="(course,index) in snakeOrderedResults(results,6)" >
```

And then a method in the vue methods section that looked like this

```
        snakeOrderedResults(results,columnsPerRow)
        {
            let ordered = []
            let totalRows = Math.ceil(results.length / columnsPerRow)

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length;  i++) {
                let rowNumber = Math.ceil((i + 1) / columnsPerRow )
                let oddRow = (rowNumber % 2)
                if (oddRow){
                    ordered[i] = results[i]
                }else{
                    let firstRowElement = ((rowNumber - 1 ) * columnsPerRow) + 1
                    let lastRowElement = (rowNumber  * columnsPerRow) 
                    let offset = (i + 1) - firstRowElement
                    let reverseIndex = lastRowElement - offset;
                    ordered[reverseIndex - 1] = results[i]
                }

            }
            return ordered
        },
```

This basically used the number of columns per row to work out if the element is on an odd or even row, and to reverse the elements of an even row.

I also had similar methods to work out whether an element was on the end of the row so I could add appropriate 'arrow' graphics, using the index of the element.

This worked responsively in Vue,i.e. when I added to the results array using an infinite scroll, it worked fine.